# conflicting declaration std::lock_guard<std::mutex>

Tags: c++, c++17, declaration

I don't understand why the following code returns an error.

```
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
}
```

lock.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

lock.cpp:5:37: error: conflicting declaration ‘std::lock_guardstd::mutex mtx’
std::lock_guardstd::mutex (mtx);

lock.cpp:4:16: note: previous declaration as ‘std::mutex mtx’
std::mutex mtx;

But, the following code compiles correctly.

```
class Test {
public:
    void lock() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx_;
};
```

But, the following code is not ok.

```
int main() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
}
```

Comment: Try `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);`

Comment: @NikitaSmirnov Assuming he's trying to `lock`  (which I think he is:) )

Comment: Comment to updated question: because in case with `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(this->mtx_);` you just create two different unnamed instances of `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`

Answer (score 3):

You declared the variable `mtx` twice

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
```

The first declaration may be equivalently rewritten like

```
std::mutex ( mtx );
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
```

Or the second declaration may be rewritten like

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mtx;
```

That is you may enclose a declarator in parentheses.

Thus the identifier `mtx` is declared twice with different types.

It seems you forgot to specify an identifier in the second declaration.:) Something like

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> my_lock( mtx );
```

**EDIT:** After you updated your question with a new code snippet

```
class Test {
public:
    void lock() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx_;
};
```

then these records

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
```

are not declarations. They are expressions that use the data member (an expression of accessing a data member) `this->mtx_`. That is the expression `this->mtx_` is not an identifier.

Comment: but code `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);`  is ok

Comment: @Pengcheng These are not declarations. That is this->mtx_ is not an identifier. These are expressions.

Comment: Is it an instance of "most vexing parse"?

Comment: @Ruslan It means only that declarators may be enclosed in parentheses. For example you may declare a two-dimensional array like  int  ( ( ( a )[M] )[N] ); Though the compiler can issue a message that the parentheses are redundent.

Comment: I mean, `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);` looks like a function (constructor (with immediate destruction)) call to me, but is in fact a declaration.

Comment: @Ruslan mtx is not a type specifier. It is a variable name. So there is no conflict with a function declaration. Also there is absent an identifier of the function.

Comment: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);` compiles, but is very far from being ok. It results in a lock being taken and then immediately released.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding out the problem:**

In first example:

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
```

Here you have declared a variable `mtx` of type `std::mutex`.
The next line is ambiguous. It can be treated as an expression with declaring a variable of type `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`, but since you do not passed a parameter to lock_guard constructor, it is being treated as a pure declaration with syntax `*type* (*identifier*)`. You can find more about resolving ambiguous [here](https://caligari.dartmouth.edu/doc/ibmcxx/en_US/doc/language/ref/rnrslvng.htm).

In second example:

```
void lock() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (this->mtx_);
}
```

You are trying to use syntax `*type* *identifier* (*constructor arguments*)`, and pass an already existent member mtx_ of your class and there is no variable name. There is no ambiguity and no errors because of absent variable name. It is just to declaration of anonymous variables.

The third example is definitely not ok because your just repeating the mistake from ex. 1 twice, by declaring two variables named `mtx`.

```
int main() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mtx);
}
```

**How to resolve:**

As I already mentioned in comment, you should better use a name for your lock. Either it can be

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
```

, or if like using parentheses to distract yourself

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(lock)(mtx);
```